Shading Google Calendar
Is there a way to shade Google Calendar, hourly?
I'd like to shade the hours that I have my kids a different color than my ex-wife's hours. Is this possible?  Is this possible on the family calendar?

I've tried unsucessfully to use events and tasks:

these aren't events but rather times when each of us is/isn't the... "oncall?" parent
I'm finding that using events litters the calendar more than I'd like, and visually get in the way
Multi-day events show across the top, and don't visually show the hourly granularity I need


the "work hours" feature does the shading I want, but

I don't know how to use work hours for our arrangement that changes day-to-day
I see that there's a way to do multiple work hour windows, but this is a clunky approach for what I'm trying to do
My Google Calendar Settings don't even show Working Hours even though I'm a paid user



